# Can I use mortar to roughly level a basement floor for workshop?

Tags: concrete

I recently got my foundation repaired and am left with a very cracked and uneven concrete floor next to the wall. Along the very edge any leveling compound would be at least an inch deep.  All I plan to do in the room is put down some epoxy floor paint and turn it into a workshop.  So basically I don't need it to be picture perfect, and self leveling compound is very expensive, so I was wondering of mortar would work well enough in this situation.  My primary concern is whether or not it would adhere well enough and whether or not such a large slab of the stuff would be prone to cracking.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Fast answer: better not :)

Answer (score 3):

Leveling using mortar is not acceptable in so many ways, but most important one is that it would crack. Even if it doesn't crack (and it will) you will have a problem because it is workshop: every time you drop a hammer or something you will damage the floor. Self-leveling compound is the best solution, by far but if that is not the option than I suggest one of two options: first would be not to touch anything; yeah it is damaged and uneven but since it is a workshop maybe you shouldn't care about it. Another solution is to make a cement screed which then would be covered with some flooring. This solution is only possible if there are no "level obstruction”; meaning all the doors can open there aren't any small steps between rooms which would be a problem for you etc.Also instead of screed you can pour thin concrete slab, but concrete should be made out of fine (small pieces) gravel.

Answer (score 2):

Mortar will most likely crumble.

To ensure good adhesion, you could cover the existing floor with PVA before mixing up some granite chips with a little sand and plenty of cement. Leave it a little low, and don't bother where you need only a thin covering, then you can cover the whole floor with a thin self-levelling screed to give you a smooth finish all over.